# Azure WorkerRole Internal Endpoints

Tags: azure

I'm trying to wrap my head around Azure... so far it seems somewhat clunky.

My perfect setup would be to have a head worker role, a DB worker role, and as many instance worker roles as I need for each "room".

My initial thought was to use internal endpoints to communicate between all of my instances. With the Head worker role, able to spawn as many instance worker roles as it needs.

I found a great msdn article that shows how to setup internal endpoints in the XML...then manually make listeners with a socket to listen for traffic on said port, but I never saw ANY code on actually SENDING data to that instant endpoint.

Another major red flag here, is that it tells me Instance Endpoints do NOT work locally in the emulator, that you MUST push to production...

Before I scrap Azure and look at other options (like VM's) can anybody explain how to send data to a worker role, and can endpoints be setup inside the emulator without pushing to the cloud every time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at using Service Bus (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/) as your communication platform and have your head Worker Role subscribe for messages.  This simplifies your need for a private network and also to understand who the publishers and subscribers are because the only component that needs to know this is the Bus.

If you wish to push large amounts of data around you can't do this via Service Bus - it can be used as a simple messaging platform only. In this scenario you would write the large blob to Azure Blob storage, place a message on the queue (most likely containing some meta data about the blob) and then your head Worker Role would read that message and trigger processing.